# Laravel 5 - DB join is returning just first table column set

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have some related MySQL tables, and I want to obtain the columns in all of them, but if I try with something like this code from the manual, I only get the columns from the first table:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

That would be all columns from 'users' table, but I do not see contacts and orders columns.

Comment: The SQL that is generated by that query is "select `users`.*, `contacts`.`phone`, `orders`.`price` from `users` inner join `contacts` on `users`.`id` = `contacts`.`user_id` inner join `orders` on `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id`" so all columns you need should be returned. Could you replace get() with toSql() and see if you're getting the same query? Could you double check that the columns you need are missing by dumping a row of returned result?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo you are right that is the SQL generated when using toSql() clause... I have changed completely my underlying code as I had to deliver my program in time... so I changed that into 2 calls, which I know is a no-no if it can be done in 1 single call... Maybe I will give it a call later (so I won't leave this one unanswered), since it is working differently in production than in development (with Homestead). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DB::table('users')->join('contacts',function($join){$join->on('users.id','=','contacts.user_id')})->join('orders',function($join){$join->on('users.id','=','orders.user_id')})->get()
```